# Как обработать в конструкторе неправильные данные?

Tags: java

Есть следующий клас:

```
public class Knowledge {
    int level;
    public Knowledge(int level) {
        if (0 < level && level < 10){
            this.level = level;
        } else {
            // что-то тут было бы правильно сделать ?
        }
    }
}
```

`Knowledge` можно оценить от 1 до 10. А что если в конструктор передатут другое число? Как правильно обработать такие параметры?

Comment: `throw new Exception("level is out of range [1,9]: " + level);`

Comment: понял, спасибо) тогда придеться в main их обрабатывать, да?

Comment: тогда следующий вопрос, а как по-правильному их обраюотать?))

Comment: Я тоже видел что можно кидать Exception, мне это не очень нравится, но иногда можно. Если есть по логике задачи какое-то дэфолтное значение, то можно присвоить его.

Comment: Либо Preconditions от google библиотека, или же уже создание своей тилиты для таких однотипных проверок, что-то на подобии этого https://github.com/GenCloud/ioc_container/blob/master/context-factory/src/main/java/org/ioc/utils/Assertion.java

Comment: Как обрабатывать - если `null`-резутьтат вызова конструктора устраивает, то продолжаете работу, иначе что-то предпринимаете...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ...
} else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("level is out of range [1,9]: " + level);
}
```

Comment: А как правильно обработать этот эксепшн, если он где-то выпрыгнет? (сори за глупые вопросы, новичок)

Comment: @TarasViyatyk Недостаточно хорошо знаю Джаву, чтобы ответить, какой подход считается хорошим тоном для обработки исключений в конструкторах (. Попробуйте задать отдельный вопрос на эту тему.